# ERROR Exception in worker process from Digital Oceanś App Platform for Django web application

Tags: django, gunicorn, digital-ocean-apps

As per DO´s [app platform documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/) I am NOT creating repository because I have repository already in my Github account. When I deployed the app as per rest of the steps mentioned in the document, deployment was successful, but runtime log returned the following errors regarding gunicorn:

> [vksite] [2023-12-19 05:44:29] [2023-12-19 05:44:29 0000] [1](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/) [INFO]
> Starting gunicorn 21.2.0 [vksite] [2023-12-19 05:44:29] [2023-12-19
> 05:44:29 0000] [1](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/) [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
> [vksite] [2023-12-19 05:44:29] [2023-12-19 05:44:29 0000] [1](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/) [INFO]
> Using worker: sync [vksite] [2023-12-19 05:44:29] [2023-12-19 05:44:29
> 0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14 [vksite] [2023-12-19
> 05:44:31] [2023-12-19 05:44:31 0000] [14] [ERROR] Exception in worker
> process ........ [vksite] [2023-12-19 05:44:31] SystemError:
> initialization of _psycopg raised unreported exception [vksite]
> [2023-12-19 05:44:31] [2023-12-19 05:44:31 0000] [14] [INFO] Worker
> exiting (pid: 14) [vksite] [2023-12-19 05:44:31] [2023-12-19 05:44:31
> 0000] [1](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/) [ERROR] Worker (pid:14) exited with code 3 [vksite]
> [2023-12-19 05:44:31] [2023-12-19 05:44:31 0000] [1](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/) [ERROR] Shutting
> down: Master [vksite] [2023-12-19 05:44:31] [2023-12-19 05:44:31 0000]
> [1](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/) [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

I´m wondering whether anyone has come across this issue? If you are, could you let me know if there is a remedy for the above error?